# error while merging summaries for tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to generate the graph for MNIST beginner tutorial but is getting the following error. For some reason, merged_summary_op object is None.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist1.py", line 48, in <module>
    summary_str = sess.run(merged_summary_op)
  File "/home/vagrant/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 307, in run
    % (subfetch, fetch, type(subfetch), e.message))
TypeError: Fetch argument None of None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a NoneType into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

I think I am missing a step here. I launched the session first and then running the statement:

```py
merged_summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same error.

In my case, adding at least one `tf.scalar_summary()` before calling `tf.merge_all_summaries()` solved the problem.

For example,

```py
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))
tf.scalar_summary("cross_entropy", cross_entropy)
merged_summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
```

I hope this snippet helps you.

Comment: I was thinking of doing the same but is still trying to understand why the example code is not collecting scalar/histogram summary: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py

Comment: Because the example code calls tf.scalar_summary() in training() defined in  mnist.py (imported by fully_connected_feed.py). See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist/mnist.py#L123

Comment: adding code to merge summaries results in the following error, otherwise runs fine. `You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' wi                                                                                                 th dtype float . . . . . . .Caused by op u'Placeholder', defined at:
  File "mnist1.py", line 9, in <module>
    x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 784])`

Comment: I assume your problem is that you are missing to specify placeholder when you run session. You must specify placeholder when running the session to merge summaries. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py#L203 is a good example.

Comment: Yes, if there is no summary preceding the call of tf.merge_all_summaries(), it will return None, which causes the exception. In the situation where one only wants to collect data from a loop, creating a non-sense scalar summary beforehand seems a bit dragging, and for my money, they should use tf.merge_summary() to collect the summary manually in this case.